# AWS Cognito SSO multiple iDPs

Tags: architecture, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, idp

Here's the scenario (using AWS Cognito via AWS Amplify):

Our company *(ExampleCorp)* is building a web application where its users will authenticate via it's own internal Active Directory (SSO).

There are also **customers** of *ExampleCorp* that will use the web app but authenticate with THEIR Active Directories (SSO).  The **customers** would then create their own users for the web app.

*ExampleCorp* would like to maintain identities for the **customer** accounts within its AD (perhaps for the purpose of permissions boundaries).

So essentially the **customer** user authenticates to the web app via it's AD but there is also a check somehow within *ExampleCorp*'s AD to ensure the **customer** account user is in the right *ExampleCorp* AD group or whatever.

Is this "double check" possible within Cognito, or does this even make sense as I've explained it?

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUKy4H_ClfROeDDNgki9pXtw/cognito-saml-with-multiple-external-idps

Answer (score 0):

If the external users are already in ExampleCorp's AD, why would you ask them to authenticate both with their own IdP (identity provider) and ExampleCorp's AD?
I'd suggest authenticating via ExampleCorp's AD only.

Or by using SAML federation based on the domain part of the email you could redirect these external users to their own IdP.

--J